# How can I avoid Access Denied error when calling TcpListener.Start() on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, mono

In my iOS application, I am trying to invoke a `TcpListener` instance. I define and start the listener as follows:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 104);
listener.Start();
```

However, I get the following exception when I run this code (iOS Simulator, iPhone, Debug mode):

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Access denied
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00051] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1111
>     at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start (Int32 backlog) [0x00022] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/TcpListener.cs:259
>     at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/TcpListener.cs:239
>     at 
> ...

Is there anything I can do to avoid the *Access denied* error, or is this a built-in restriction of the Mono runtime on Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: you can't bind to ports < 1024 without administrative privileges. Use a port > 1024 for this purpose. This is a general restriction - you would encounter the same problem on windows if running as an ordinary user. This is noted in the wikipedia page for DICOM

Comment: Thanks, @Petesh. I have tried with ports > 1024, but I get the same error message.

Comment: At this stage, I don't know. Binding to INADDR_ANY on iOS works for native apps. The use of port 104 was the biggest red flag I saw in your code

Comment: OK, that's good to know. Do you know if there are any configurations required to enable TCP listening? I cannot find anything specific in the Xamarin Studio iOS project settings, but maybe there is some required custom command or?

Comment: You mught want to check that the new port you've selected is not already in use by using `netstat -ln | grep <port>`.

Comment: Using a port > 1024 (1304 to be exact) worked fine for me.

Comment: The code actually seems to work when I deploy it on my iPhone; do I need to configure the iOS Simulator in some way to allow TCP listening there as well? It would facilitate debugging considerably for me if I could run the code on the simulator.

Comment: OK, further tests using a higher port number proved successful. @Petesh, you were right about the port number all along, so if you turn your first comment into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't bind to ports < `1024` without administrative privileges. Use a port >= `1024` for this purpose. This is a general restriction - you would encounter the same problem on any application if running as an ordinary user in most operating systems.

This is noted in the [wikipedia page for DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM), where it gives the list of ports:

> DICOM have reserved the following TCP and UDP port numbers by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA):
>
> - `104` well-known port for DICOM over Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) or User Datagram Protocol (UDP). Since 104 is in *the reserved subset, many operating systems require special privileges to use it*.
> - `2761` registered port for DICOM using Integrated Secure Communication Layer (ISCL) over TCP or UDP
> - `2762` registered port for DICOM using Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP or UDP
> - `11112` registered port for DICOM using standard, open communication over TCP or UDP
>
> The standard recommends but does not require the use of these port numbers.

(page from wikipedia, emphasis mine)